# Polymer, send a picture with ajax-form

Tags: php, html, image, polymer

I actually try to send a picture on my server but he doesn't receive this.

My form :

```html
<form is="ajax-form" action="../../../back/saveIMG.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    
  <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic "accept="image/*">

  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submitInfo">
</form>
```

And my php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILE["pic"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
var_dump($_POST);
if(isset($_POST["submitInfo"])) {

    $check = getimagesize($_FILE["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
var_dump($uploadOk);
if ($uploadOk == 1) {
    $res = move_uploaded_file($_FILE["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    var_dump($res);
}
```

?>

My script normaly run, i test it previously but he just receive a post array with the picture's name.

Comment: From where do You have `$file` variable? Do You use `$_FILE`?

Comment: Sorry i edit this but my probleme is the same, when i try to var_dump $_FILE that give me an empty array. With $_POST i have this: array[1]{"picture.png"}

Comment: Do You have any other field (for ex. text field) named "pic" or is this the only field in the form?

Comment: I give you my complet form they are any other field

Comment: You wrote, that You send it via AJAX. Can You show Your JavaScript code?

Comment: I haven't javascript for this form! I'm oblige to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JavaScript needed. The file is being sent, and you can verify by looking at the network tab in the dev tools of your choice.

To get a handle on the PHP representation of the file: `$_FILES['pic'];`. The file bytes will be stored at `$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']`. For more examples, have a look at the [Fine Uploader PHP server-side example](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/php/traditional/handler.php), which handles files uploaded via an unrelated JavaScript library.

Ajax-form will send the file just like a traditional form provided that the browser supports the File API. If you are using IE9 or older you are out of luck.

While you can use a simple `<input type="file">`, you can also use the [`<file-input>` element](https://github.com/rnicholus/file-input). Disclaimer: I wrote `<file-input>`, the ajax-form element, and [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).

Comment: Thanks, that work fine, I try to use this on mobile safari but he not firing on-change or on-blur event. Another way to see when a <file-input> have a file ?

Comment: Another question i use a core-icon to make a texture for the file-input but how can I use the basic appearance of input type="file"? (Maybe it's an issue but my file-input are invisible without core-icon)